# pipeline processing using cat

Tags: bash, cat

original:

```
./A_process.py _ < input.dict > output.dict.tmp
./B_process.py _ < output.dict.tmp > output.dict
rm output.dict.tmp
```

I am trying to make it into a pipeline, so

```
cat input.dict | A_process.py _ | B_process.py _ > output.dict
```

however it shows "A_process.py command not found"...

I guess something wrong with the environment, but not sure what to do.

Comment: `./A_process.py` will look in the current directory for `A_process.py` whereas `A_process.py` will only search your `PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @steeldriver wrote in his comment, the problem you are facing is that the script you are executing is not in your `PATH`

The simple solution will be to add the prefix `./` to the script-name, assuming that you are running the command in the same folder the script is located:

```
cat input.dict | ./A_process.py _ | ./B_process.py _ > output.dict
```

Other options might be:

- Add the path of the script location into the `PATH` variable.
- Instead of `./script_name` use full-path of the script `/full/path/to/script/directory/A_process.py`